# Real device : Error connecting to the service protocol

Tags: android, flutter, dart, real-time

Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:56142/Y0oweCwQNFI=/
i get this error when i debug my code with run an debug button and the device shows a white screen
but when i write in the terminal "flutter run" the app works perfectly

i want to debug the app using the button so  can see the results in my console and a real time porfermence